# What is meant by binding strength of binary operators?

Tags: logic, notation

Dr Frederic P. Scheuller writes at 33:55 of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V49i_LM8B0E&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic) the decreasing order of binding strength in the sequence:

$$\neg,  \wedge , \lor , \implies, \iff$$

But what does it mean for binary operators to have binding strength?

Comment: I believe it refers to order of operations.  The more tightly bound operators you do first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the immediate context, he is describing the order of operations for logical operators.

$\lnot$ has highest precedence, then $\land$, then $\lor$, then $\to$, then $\leftrightarrow$.

According to this, if you see $A \land B \leftrightarrow C$ you should interpret it as $(A \land B) \leftrightarrow C$ because $\land$ binds more tightly than $\leftrightarrow$.  It is similar to the order of arithmetic operations where multiply and divide bind more tightly than add and subtract.

Additionally, with this formulation, formulas written in [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) can be parenthesis free without introducing ambiguity.

$$ A \land \lnot B \land \lnot C \;\lor\; \lnot D \land E \land F  $$

Comment: Oh so like BODMAS, what is the motivation behind this order though?

Comment: The motivation is to minimize the number of parentheses. This order is good, if we imagine the opposite order with $\leftrightarrow$ highest and $\lnot$ lowest, we would need parentheses more often. When it appears, $\leftrightarrow$ is frequently a toplevel connective signifying a theorem. Also $\land$ and $\lor$ are associative, and $\to$ is usually treated as right-associative, so giving them their own precedence levels makes sense. [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) is an alternative notation for logic that only has binary operators and is parenthesis free.